I am using IEDriverServer to automate Edge in IE mode. But my application open new window on click of button and it is not recognising the new window
var ieOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions();

ieOptions.AttachToEdgeChrome = true;

//change the path accordingly

ieOptions.EdgeExecutablePath = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft/Edge/Application/msedge.exe";

var driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieOptions);

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("url");

var initialHandleCount = driver.WindowHandles.Count;

driver.FindElement(By.Id("_idJsp9")).Click();

var newHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
while (newHandles.Count == initialHandleCount)


{
   newHandles = driver.WindowHandles;
}

this is going into infinite loop as windowHandles count is not increasing even though new window is opened
I tried with IEDriverServer 32 and 64 bit latest versions. Using both also it is the same issue.
Any suggestions/ other ways to solve this issue.
